# Android library (jar) needs functionality from another library

Tags: java, android, jar, java-native-interface

I'm trying to write an android library which takes functionality from another library, the problem is in essence there's an in app billing library and I want to write an interface to it as a separate jar library to be included in a project.

How can I do this if it's at all possible? If not what are my options? I tried building the classes in my jar library but when I try to invoke functions from the other library I get the following error:

> AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Full logcat:

> --------- beginning of /dev/log/system
>   --------- beginning of /dev/log/main D/Unity   (14530): GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap
>   GL_NV_depth_nonlinear GL_NV_draw_path GL_NV_texture_npot_2D_mipmap
>   GL_OE S_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_vertex_half_float
>   GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_NV_draw_buffers GL_NV_multiview_draw_buffers
>   GL_EXT_Cg_shader GL_EX T_packed_float GL_OES_texture_half_float
>   GL_EXT_texture_array GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
>   GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc GL_NV_texture_compre ssion_latc
>   GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc
>   GL_NV_texture_compression_s3tc GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
>   GL_NV_get_ tex_image GL_NV_read_buffer GL_NV_shader_framebuffer_fetch
>   GL_NV_copy_image GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments GL_EXT_bgra
>   GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_ EXT_unpack_subimage
>   GL_NV_pack_subimage GL_NV_texture_compression_s3tc_update
>   GL_NV_read_depth GL_NV_read_stencil GL_NV_uniform_buffer_object
>   GL_EXT_r obustness GL_OES_standard_derivatives
>   GL_NV_EGL_stream_consumer_external GL_NV_3dvision_settings
>   GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_debug_label GL_NV_ D/Unity   (14530):
>   coverage_sample GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean GL_NV_timer_query
>   I/Unity   (14530): AndroidJavaException:
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError I/Unity   (14530):   at
>   UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x00000] in :0 I/Unity   (14530):   at
>   UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CallStringMethod (IntPtr obj, IntPtr
>   methodID, UnityEngine.jvalue[] args) [0x00000] in :0 I/Unity   (14530):   at
>   UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._Call[String] (System.String methodName,
>   System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in :0
>
> I/Unity   (14530):   at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.Call[String]
>   (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in
>   :0
>
> I/Unity   (14530):   at CallJavaCode.Start () [0x00000] in :0 I/Unity   (14530): I/Unity   (14530): (Filename:  Line: -1)

Comment: Please add the full stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I could print the stack trace from the exception in Java, when I did that I noticed it was asking about calling Looper.prepare(), when I called that function first it fixed the problem I was having.

The way i integrated the functionality from the other jar was to simply merge their contents.